# Laravel update() method yielding 'x doesn't have a default value' error

Tags: php, laravel, controller, updates

I have a form which takes in the following values: stage_name, stage_type, 'client_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'

I was able to create a method for adding a new item in the table, however in attempting to update it I came across this error:

"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'client_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `stages` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2020-05-21 02:43:53, 2020-05-21 02:43:53))"

My controller update function:

```
public function update(Request $request, Stage $stage)
{
    $request->validate([
        'stage_name'   => 'required|max:300',
        'stage_type'   => 'required'
    ]);

    $client = Auth::user()->client_id;

    $stage->update([
        'stage_name'          => $request-> stage_name,
        'stage_type'     => $request->stage_type,
        'client_id'   => $client, 
    ]);

    $stage->save();

    return $stage;
}
```

Even if I directly define client_id => 1 it still yields the same error

Comment: check if route model binding is working or not. Do `dd($stage);` on the first line of function and check right data is being fetched. And check your Route file to see if the type-hinted variable name `$stage` match a route segment name `../{stage}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using empty save() function `$stage->save();` and you are not defining the record which should update. Simply use:-

```
$stage->where($column,$value) //othervise it will update all the records.
       ->update([
        'stage_name'          => $request-> stage_name,
        'stage_type'     => $request->stage_type,
        'client_id'   => $client, 
    ]);
```

This code is sufficient to update the recorded not need to add save(). If you wanna using save then follow the below code.

```
$stage = $stage->find($id);
$stage->stage_name = $request->stage_name;
$stage->stage_type = $request->stage_type;
$stage->client_id = $request->client;
$stage->save()
```

You mixed the both approaches.

Comment: In your blade template add an hidden field with the name of column and add the protected fillable for the column that you got the error.

Comment: The OP is using Route Model Binding so $stage should already load the Stage model. It should not be empty, `update()` method should work. But yeah `$stage->save()` is not needed. It already failed at `update()`. Using Laravel's route model binding you don't need to explicitly define query to fetch the model